# Checkmark not appearing in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have written a program which stores a set of objects under a label and the labels can be viewed and changed later. I have written the following code for that(just including the portions that adds the check mark):

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; //To avoid the blue selection
//necessary codes to populate the table here
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
return cell;
}
```

But the table is not even showing any check mark. Yes, i tried again by commenting off `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`, still no use. I haven't written any code elsewhere for unchecking the checkmark already made.

Comment: try cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

Comment: What you have there is infinite recursion.

Comment: Infinite recursion?? How?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT you are calling the same method again & again(recursive call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you setting the accessory type like this
`[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType`, since you are getting the cell itself in this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
     { 
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; //To avoid the blue selection
       //necessary codes to populate the table here
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; //Do like this   
       return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

with

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the checkmark appear use

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```